# How to install drivers for 32bits or 64 bits with inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to create **1 SINGLE setup.exe file** to install a PC sofwtare.
Problem is: this sofwtares uses a signed driver : 1 32bits version and 1 64 bits version.

After 3 days of searching, I got a clue from the driver developper:

I  guess  that your installer is 32-bit, and you are trying to install
the driver on 64-bit system. See the FAQ question:

Q: Unable to programmatically install the driver from 32-bit process on Vista\7 x64.
The driver is always saved to windows\SysWOW64\drivers instead of windows\system32\drivers and can't start.

A: This is a feature of 64-bit Windows called "virtualization".
It  is  applied  to 32-bit applications. Windows redirects file system
and  registry  calls to different locations, used as an alternate view
of the standard folders and registry keys:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249%28VS.85%29.aspx

The following ways can be used to install the driver properly on x64:

- Call API function Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection from 32-bit
  installer before saving the driver to windows\system32\drivers:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743(VS.85).aspx
  It is possible to do this using System plug-in in NSIS, and using
  direct API call in other installers.

There is an InnoSetup function that can help to avoid issues on x64:
http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_enablefsredirection

Anyone can help me with that ?

Answer (score -1):

Below is how I installed 32-bit drivers on a 32 bit machine and 64-bit drivers to a 64-bit machine.

Source: "C:\BDT\SysWOW64*"; DestDir: "{app}";Check: Is64BitInstallMode 
Source: "C:\BDT\system32*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Check: not Is64BitInstallMode

Comment: The question is about installing the drivers to `windows\system32\drivers`, not `{app}`.

Comment: Change to DestDir: "{windows\system32\drivers}";  or DestDir: "{C:\Windows\SysWOW64}"